# What do I have to use in China to replace Google maps in my app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Currently living in Beijing, I'm developing an app and since China is an important market, I would like to use another API than google map to make the maps features in my app work there as well ( for the rest of the world, the users will use Google map ).

Since the user has to be able to navigate worldwide on the map, and not only being limited to China when the user is there without a VPN, I heard that baidu map could be too restricting ( some people say that it's limited to China in term of search, or that it's not working properly when looking outside ), I was thinking about using gaode (http://ditu.amap.com/), but the doc is difficult to find as I don't speak Chinese...

Do you guys know where I can find some examples or simple implementations I could use to get started, or if I should look for something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: open street maps is a community based maps project -- https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/25248662

Comment: Thanks man, I'm gonna give a try ( and try whether it's blocked or not :D )

Comment: i had no idea Gmaps was blocked over there, interesting.  How about using a webview and use Gmaps API 3 with gmaps.js  https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/ to display maps easy. you can then pass parameters lat,lng  via url and do whatever with the map. or have blocked the web gmaps too

Comment: Since it has to keep a map with the last informations downloaded when the app will be used offline I don't kmow if it could suits with what I need, also it generates more internet traffic which can make the app a bit less reponsive. I'll will check this anyway, maybe it could be a solution because for the moment, the app was made with google maps for the non-chinese users..